# How to stretch ListView buttons to full width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

My activity_main.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/MyListItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```

My mainactivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] mMonthArray = { "Январь", "Февраль", "Котомарт", "Апрель", "Май",
            "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь",
            "Декабрь" };

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mMonthAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView myListView = findViewById(R.id.MyListItem);
        mMonthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMonthArray);
        myListView.setAdapter(mMonthAdapter);

    }
}
```

My buttons in ListView haven't full width as ListView:

[image]

Comment: set android:layout_width="match_parent" or create a view to custom each item in listview with adapter

Comment: make button width to match_parent in item row layout

Comment: Can you show me an example of the code? I'm a noob and I don't understand in words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ListView wraps to content width. Try to change the width to match_parent like below.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/MyListItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
```